# multi upload to mongodb gfs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, multer

```
app.post("/", upload.single("avatar"), function(req, res, next){
    var writestream = gfs.createWriteStream({
        filename: req.file.filename
    });  
    fs.createReadStream("./uploads/kkm/" + req.file.filename)    
      .on("end", function() {
          fs.unlink("./uploads/kkm/"+ req.file.filename, function(err) {
              res.send("success") 
          })
      })  
      .pipe(writestream);    
});
```

I want to upload 2 images to mongodb, I can create write and read streams for one image but lost idea for two files.

I can pipe for one image but not two. When I try array medthod, it replys

> "TypeError: Cannot read property 'filename' of undefined" ERROR.

My goal is to upload two files to mongodb in one method or what ever at once. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GridFS methods insert one file per call but you can easily achieve that. You need to use loop in your Node.JS application and send the file one by one to GridFS.

if you use multer you can do something like this

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, callback) => {
        callback(null, './.temp/uploads');
    },
    filename: (req, file, callback) => {
        callback(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now());
    }
});
const multerOptions = {
    storage: storage
};

const upload = multer(multerOptions).array('files[]');

module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
  upload(req, res, (err) => {
        for (let i in req.files) {
            const file = req.files[i];
            // here you can call GridFS method and upload the file
        }
  });
});
```

Comment: I understand what you mean. but I don't know how to do. Could you please give me clue or example ?

Comment: Sure I updated the answer with code for you if you still don't understand it I'm here to explain

Answer (score 0):

```
 app.post('/upload', function(request, response) {
  upload(request, response, function(err) {  

 var files = new Array (req.file.filename,req.file.namedName) 
    for(var i = 0 ; i < files.length; i++) 
{ 
// here you can call GridFS method 
 }
});
```

- Thanks for your help @Ariel Henryson.
- I did in my way looping and it works.
- I try various times your method.
- I do not know how to use *module.exports = (req, res, next) => {*
  method it replys cannot post error and it shows syntax error as well.
- Where do you use app.post method .
- If you don't mind, could you please write full code, doesn't matter
  if not.